# (Sequelize) Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: node.js, relacionamento, sequelize-js

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de carrinho para ecommerce, e dentro do Model Cart, fiz um relacionamento com Model de User e o Model de Product, para que eu possa acessar os dois itens através do Cart. No entanto, ele não reconhece os campos dos outros models (Product e User). Códigos:

**Product.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Category = require('./Category.js')
const connect = require('./Database.js')

const Product = connect.define('products', {
    
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(120),
        allowNull: false
    },

    slug: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    image: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    price: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false    
    },

    body: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

Category.hasMany(Product)
Product.belongsTo(Category)

Product.sync({ force: false })

module.exports = Product
```

**User.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const connect = require('./Database.js')

const User = connect.define('users', {
    
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(120),
        allowNull: false
    },

    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },

    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    cellphone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(15),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },

    is_staff: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
})

User.sync({ force: false })

module.exports = User
```

**Cart.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Product = require('./Product.js')
const User = require('./User.js')
const connect = require('./Database.js')

const Cart = connect.define('carts', {
    quantity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: 1
    }

})

Cart.belongsTo(Product)
Cart.belongsTo(User)

Cart.sync({ force: true })

module.exports = Cart
```

[Imagem do Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQzCG.png)

Comment: O erro está acontecendo na consulta das informações aparentemente, você só colocou as definições dos modelos, poste o código onde a consulta no banco de dados é feita para conseguirmos ajudar

Comment: Eu usei o findAll() normal, tentei por o include mas dava outros erros.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está acontecendo na consulta das informações aparentemente, você só colocou as definições dos modelos, poste o código onde a consulta no banco de dados é feita para conseguirmos ajudar, mas há algo que você pode tentar.

Sequelize não inclui na consulta por padrão as entidades mapeadas dentro da entitidade que está sendo buscada, na documentação é citado o uso do **include**:

```
await User.findAll({ include: Task });
```

Resultado:

```
[{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "tasks": [{
    "name": "A Task",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1
  }]
}]
```

Um array pode ser passado pra propridade include, algo como:

```
await User.findAll({ include: [Task, OutraTabela] });
```

Informações tiradas da [documentação do sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html).

Comment: Eu tentei usar o include, porém dava outros erros, erro do "as", de associação...